# has_secure_password: how to require minimum length

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I require that a password has a minimum length when using has_secure_password in Rails 3.1? I tried to do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ... 
    validates :password, presence: { on: create }, length { minimum: 8 }
    ...
end
```

but then the validation fails with password "too short" on update when password is not provided in form params. For other attributes length is only validated if the value for the field is provided. Is this a bug in the has_secure_password implementation or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
validates :password, presence: { on: create }, length { minimum: 8 }, :if => :password_changed?
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think you mean: validates :password, presence: { on: create }, length { minimum: 8, if: password_digest_changed? }. If I would do the :if at the end like you suggest the validates :presence might not be active on create. There is no method password_changed? since I am using has_secure_password--the relevant method is password_digest_changed?. This is a bug in Rails 3.1.rc4, right?

Comment: Hi, well done :) I don't think it's a bug, `password` in your case seems to be a virtual attribute and methods like `changed?` only exist for db rows

Comment: This solution will not work as @apneadiving pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }, if: :password_digest_changed?
```

Now this validation will run on any attempt to update the password, and it wont break otherwise, @apneaddiving's answer was good but it had some small sintax issues and would only run on creation, so any update on password wouldn't be validated.